# Transferring only visible rows without using .select or .End(xlDown)

Tags: vba, excel

The code currently filters the data the way I need it to but when it copies it over it copies everything not just the filtered data. I know I can make it work using .select and then copying and pasting etc. but I would rather avoid that if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Auto_Filter()

    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim Open_Jobs_Report As Worksheet
        Set Open_Jobs_Report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Jobs Report")
    Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
        Set Dashboard = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    Dim PersonResponsible As Range
    Dim Violations As Range
    Dim CLM1 As Long
    Dim CLM2 As Long


            With Sheets("Open Jobs Report")
                Set RNG = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
                RNG.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>"

                CLM1 = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="Person Responsible").Column
                    Set PersonResponsible = .Range(.Cells(1, CLM1), .Cells(1, CLM1).End(xlDown))
                CLM2 = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="Violations").Column
                    Set Violations = .Range(.Cells(1, CLM2), .Cells(1, CLM2).End(xlDown))

            End With





                Dashboard.Range("B4:B1000").Value = PersonResponsible.Value
                Dashboard.Range("E4:E1000").Value = Violations.Value

                    Dashboard.Range("B4:B1000").RemoveDuplicates , Header:=xlYes
                    Dashboard.Range("E4:E1000").RemoveDuplicates , Header:=xlYes




            Open_Jobs_Report.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData


    End Sub
```

Comment: Look into [Range.SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only copy the visible rows from your table on the `Open_Jobs_Report` sheet

```
Open_Jobs_Report.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

---

**Update after comments:**

```
With Open_Jobs_Report.ListObjects(1)
    Union(.ListColumns(9).DataBodyRange, .ListColumns(19).DataBodyRange).Copy
End With
```

Or using header names:

```
With Open_Jobs_Report.ListObjects(1)
    Union(.ListColumns("Person Responsible").DataBodyRange, .ListColumns("Violations").DataBodyRange).Copy
End With
```

Thinking a bit more about it this is how I'd probably go about doing it:

```
Dim Open_Jobs_Report As Worksheet
Dim temp as Variant

Set Open_Jobs_Report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Jobs Report")

temp = Open_Jobs_Report.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

With Dashboard
    .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(3 + UBound(temp,1), 2)).Value = Application.Index(temp, , 9)
    .Range(.cells(4, 5), .Cells(3 + UBound(temp, 1), 5)).Value = Application.Index(temp, , 19)
End With
```

This puts the entire visible part of the table into an array in memory and then sets the range equal to the bits you're interested in.

Comment: Is it possible to modify it so it only picks up columns "S" and "I"?

Comment: What's the headers of your table?

Comment: Person Responsible and Violations

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. Using either column positions or header names.

Comment: Brilliant! Is there anything special about the syntax for pasting them or does it work with just .paste from there? To clarify, I need to paste them into Dashboard B and E in the first currently unused rows.

Comment: It should just work with `.paste` as normal. All we've changed is how we selected the range for copying. You could however avoid copy and paste and just make a range equal to the column. Which would probably use less of an overhead

Comment: That is what I was trying to do with Dashboard.Range("B4:B1000").Value = PersonResponsible.Value
                Dashboard.Range("E4:E1000").Value = Violations.Value but I am not sure how to make it work with just the filtered rows

Comment: Have a look at the last bit. It is quite a bit different from the others as it uses an array. If you want to use this method (which I highly recommend) You could do your entire data manipulation of the table in the array (i.e. in memory instead of in sheet - much quicker) before feeding back the results to your Dashboard. You could also reference the column positions using the `.ListColumns("Violations")` and `.ListColumns("Person Responsible)` methods instead of trying to find their positions

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping to do in the beginning. I just didn't know how to structure it. I inserted your bottom suggestion of code but I am getting a type mismatch on the temp = line. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've just updated it - it's probably a spelling mistake somewhere (I was free typing in here instead of writing it in the VBA editor)

Comment: It is only doing it for the first line of data. Should I just throw it in a loop or is there a better way to get it to move all of the data over?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113059/discussion-between-tom-and-tonyp).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to use the the built-in AutoFilter.Range object of the worksheet.

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Paste
```

[This link gives the full explanation](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/a-better-way-to-copy-filtered-rows-using-vba/)

Comment: Is it possible to modify it so it only picks up columns "S" and "I"?